# How to redirect from port 80 to port 8443 using Tomcat and iptables

Tags: linux, tomcat, redirect

I have the following iptable entry:

```
REDIRECT   tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http redir ports 8443
```

In my server.xml, I have **only** the following connector:

```
<Connector port="8443" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
                   maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75"
                   enableLookups="false" disableUploadTimeout="true"
                   acceptCount="100" scheme="https" secure="true"
                   clientAuth="false" sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2" SSLEnabled="true"
                   URIEncoding="UTF-8" keyAlias="tomcat" keystorePass="pass" keystoreFile="/home/myhome/.keystore" />
```

When I use http say from Firefox, I see a GET request for a small (7 bytes) file with type application/octet-stream instead of the page that I would get if using https.  I'm using Ubuntu 18 and Tomcat 8.

How can I configure to redirect http to https?

Comment: Most likely has nothing to do with iptables. Check your application and your server.xml.

Comment: Thanks Michael. I'm looking at it now but I don't see any reference to the "download" file in server.xml or web.xml.

Comment: You won't. It's a generic name that Firefox gives when you send a `Content-Disposition: attachment` with no filename, and/or a zero byte file. You should pop open your browser's developer tools and look at the actual requests and responses.

Comment: Firefox developer tools shows only a GET of type octet-stream. Btw- when I take out the http rule to redirect, I don't get the file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are trying to redirect a plain HTTP port to HTTPS.

The browser expects plaintext, but gets an SSL Stream, that is what you get offered for download.

You should use HTTP to redirect to HTTPS, not IPTables.

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
       connectionTimeout="20000"
       URIEncoding="UTF-8"
       redirectPort="8443" />
```

You could still use IPTables to redirect 80 to 8080 and 443 to 8443. But better solution would be to use a reverse proxy in front of your tomcat to handle the default ports.

Comment: Thanks. I used iptables with both redirect entries and then set redirectPort to 443 in the server.xml. I also added a security constraint with transport guarantee of CONFIDENTIAL for all URLs to my web.xml.